# Change background color outside of the body in Rmarkdown

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I am looking to change the color of the drawn area in Rmarkdown, but I can't seem to find the div targeting just it. If I apply it to the body, everything changes color

[image: Example Code]

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline CSS or a CSS chunk.

````
---
title: "TEST"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_collapsed: true
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
theme: lumen
---

```{css echo = FALSE}
body{
background-color: black;
}
```


# cardiology
# cardiology
# cardiology
# cardiology
# cardiology

This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. 
This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This     is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a paragraph. This is a     paragraph. This is a paragraph.
````

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the css, the .body can be assigned to the background color of the exterior part, while changing the background color inside the .toc-content class will change the inside to the desired one

```
.toc-content{
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}
body{
  background-color: black;
}
```